# JSOUP error fetching url Status 401

Tags: url, jsoup

`org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=401, URL= anyurl
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:465)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)`

What I am trying to do is a redirect from a url that needs authentication. The url works fine when I open it in my browser, but doesn't work while using Jsoup. Anybody who has solved this issue?

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36")
    .timeout(0).get();
```

Comment: Please provide some code. For all we know, you might be doing anything, and the stack trace isn't enough to determine whats wrong!

Comment: Added the code for your reference